# Restrict Trajectory on Z axis

Tags: unity, c#

I have a cube which I select on mouse and point out the location to throw the cube with trajectory dots.

The code is working fine, but I need to restrict the trajectory dots position on z axis so the user could not be able to throw it towards z axis.

Here is my code

```
   if (cubePlane.Raycast(camRay, out enter))
            {
                cubeisClicked2 = true;
                fingerPosition = camRay.GetPoint(enter);

                cubeFingerDiff = cubePosition - fingerPosition;
                ShotForce = new Vector3(cubeFingerDiff.x * shootingPowerX, cubeFingerDiff.y * shootingPowerY, 0);
                if (cubeFingerDiff.magnitude > 0.4f)
                {
                    trajectoryDots.SetActive(true);

                }
                else
                {
                    trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);
                }

                for (int dotNumber = 0; dotNumber < NumberOfDots; dotNumber++)
                {
                    x1 = cubePosition.x + ShotForce.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
                    y1 = cubePosition.y + ShotForce.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift) + (Physics.gravity.y / 2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift) * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift));
                    z1 = cubePosition.z + ShotForce.z * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
                    Dots[dotNumber].transform.position = new Vector3(x1, y1, 0f);
                }
            }
        }
```

I set the z axis to zero every where but still able point towards z axis.

**Note:** It is 3D game not 2D

Comment: try ```cubeFingerDiff.z = 0``` after ```cubeFingerDiff = cubePosition - fingerPosition;```

Comment: you may see I use z as 0 in the following code
 ShotForce = new Vector3(cubeFingerDiff.x * shootingPowerX, cubeFingerDiff.y * shootingPowerY, 0);